# How do I continue display:inline after a button onClick event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I used button onClick to activate the display:inline of the textbox2 with other dropdownlist2 using the onchange event of the dropdownlist1 in the Update panel and send the value to the server.

Read the value of dropdownlist1 in the page_load section of the server to continue the display:inline processing of dropdownlist2 and textbox2 button onclick event occurs and the page is rendered and is processed again as display:none.

Debugging confirmed that the dropdownlist1 values are correctly entered and the display:inline code of dropdownlist2 is executed, and I don't know why.

```
script

        function DisplayDate(ddlDate) {
            var Control = document.getElementById(ddlDate.id);

            if (Control.value == 2) {
                document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlSearch_Date').style.display = 'inline';
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlSearch_Date').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDate1').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDate2').style.display = 'none';
            }
        }

aspx
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updSearch" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>

            <div>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSearch_Type" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-outline btn-primary dropdown-toggle" onchange="DisplayDate(this)">
                </asp:DropDownList>

                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSearch_Date" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-outline btn-primary dropdown-toggle" Style="display: none;">
                </asp:DropDownList>

                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate1" runat="server" placeholder="Search..." TextMode="Date" CssClass="form-control text-1" Width="150px" Style="text-align: center; display: none;"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate2" runat="server" placeholder="Search..." TextMode="Date" CssClass="form-control text-1" Width="150px" Style="text-align: center; display: none;"></asp:TextBox>

                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSearch2" runat="server" OnClientClick="Searching();" CssClass="btn btn-primary text-1 p-2" Style="height: 37px; text-align: center; display: inline;"><i class="fas fa-search m-0"></i></asp:LinkButton>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

page_load

if(ddlSearch_Type.SelectedValue == "1")
                {
                    ddlSearch_Type.Attributes.Add("display", "inline");
                    txtDate1.Attributes.Add("display", "inline");
                    txtDate2.Attributes.Add("display", "inline");
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of your code

```
if(ddlSearch_Type.SelectedValue == "1")
                {
                    ddlSearch_Type.Attributes.Add("display", "inline");
                    txtDate1.Attributes.Add("display", "inline");
                    txtDate2.Attributes.Add("display", "inline");
                }
```

You need to change it to

```
if(ddlSearch_Type.SelectedValue == "1")
                {
                    ddlSearch_Type.Style.Add("display", "inline");
                    txtDate1.Style.Add("display", "inline");
                    txtDate2.Style.Add("display", "inline");
                }
```

as display is style attribute not html attribute.